# ValueError: Dimensions 36 and 78 are not compatible error while converting graph data from pytroch to tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, pytorch-geometric, tensorflow-gnn

I want to convert my graph data created using pytorch to tensorflow. to train graph neural network using tensorflow library. I am getting ValueError: Dimensions 36 and 78 are not compatible error .How to solve this.
My data is like below:
[Data(x=[36, 8], edge_index=[2, 78], y=[78]), Data(x=[31, 8], edge_index=[2, 77], y=[77]), Data(x=[17, 8], edge_index=[2, 33], y=[33])]

code I am using:

import tensorflow as tf
def convert_to_tf_dataset(data):
return tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data.x.numpy(), data.edge_index.numpy(), data.y.numpy()))
convert_to_tf_dataset(dataset_row[0]) # to convert jsut single data point in the list of dataset.

Error:
ValueError: Dimensions 36 and 2 are not compatible

If i try to reshape it it is showing another valueerror
Error:
ValueError: Dimensions 36 and 78 are not compatible

How to solve this